# How to query a single node with xquery so that the result has a different tag?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, nosql, xquery, flwor

How can I [adjust](http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPs4) the `xquery` below so that the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Sex>F</Sex>
```

xml:

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <entry>Reported_Date</entry>
    <entry>HA</entry>
    <entry>Sex</entry>
    <entry>Age_Group</entry>
    <entry>Classification_Reported</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-01-26</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-02</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>50-59</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>20-29</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-11</entry>
    <entry>Interior</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-20</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-21</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-27</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>60-69</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

xquery:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

for $x in /csv

return $x/record[3]/entry[3]
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>F</entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead

```
for $x in /csv
return
<Sex>
  {$x/record[3]/entry[3]/text()}
</Sex>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Sex>F</Sex>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if, like me, you don't like unnecessary variables, you can also do (in 3.1)

```
/csv/record[3]/entry[3] ! <Sex>{string(.)}</Sex>
```